# How to replace a value by null?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a column data['Rating-Mean'] which has values [0,1,2,3,4,5].

How do I replace value=0 by null (nan)?

I've tried:

```
data['Rating-Mean'].loc[:, data['Rating-Mean'] == 0] = np.nan
```

Thanks.

Comment: `data.loc[data['Rating-Mean'] == 0, 'Rating-Mean'] = np.nan`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use replace

```
data['Rating-Mean'] = data['Rating-Mean'].replace([0], None)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, that was super easy...

```
data['Book-Rating'] = data['Book-Rating'].replace(0, None)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [numpy.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to solve your query

```
import numpy as np

data['Rating-Mean'] = np.where(data['Rating-Mean'] == 0, np.nan, data['Rating-Mean'])
```

Using `numpy` is very straight forward and it makes your computations faster!